# Filter column / row data in matrix through user input - matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, input, filtering

I have an N x 3 matrix (double) with values in third column going in the interval 1:4, and only those four values. This matrix is saved as 'data', and will be used for further analysis after this filtering with the same name.

How can I through user input (not popup) sort the rows with several conditions, eg I want to filter for rows with third column values with numbers 1 and 3 (or 1 and 2, or 1 and 2 and 4, or only 3 and so on)?

I also have to take care of displaying an error message on invalid input (eg input is empty or invalid number like '6' as well as combinations of wrong inputs like filtering for '1', '2' and '7') and letting the user retry the input.

I am using matlab.

---

The matrix could look something like this

```
42.34 0.73713 1
25.387 0.8774 1
57.187 0.388 2
37.458 0.7095 2
34.227 0.6929 2
47.837 0.61363 2
30.852 0.65929 2
51.329 0.50498 3
29.501 0.77894 3
34.895 0.80504 3
26.243 0.73048 3
22.311 0.65362 3
14.769 0.17958 4
17.326 0.23037 4
41.557 0.38979 4
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this could work. The input could be a number or a vector, for example `1`, `[1 2]` or `[1:3]`

```
filter=[];

while isempty(filter) || ~isvector(filter) || ischar(filter)
    filter=input('Enter rows to filter: ')
end

index=[];

m=[[42.34 0.73713 1];
[25.387 0.8774 1];
[57.187 0.388 2];
[37.458 0.7095 2];
[34.227 0.6929 2];
[47.837 0.61363 2];
[30.852 0.65929 2];
[51.329 0.50498 3];
[29.501 0.77894 3];
[34.895 0.80504 3];
[26.243 0.73048 3];
[22.311 0.65362 3];
[14.769 0.17958 4];
[17.326 0.23037 4];
[41.557 0.38979 4]]

for i=1:numel(filter)
    index=[index find(m(:,3)==filter(i))'];
end

m2=m(index,:)
```

You can change the matrix definition for any matrix loaded as you stated in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really is a good option, but how would you handle an incorrect input?

Comment: I made a little adjustment to the code in order to ask the user for a value in case that the filter is not a vector, or is a char or is empty. Do you have in mind any other option?